# Slide Effect for iOS

Tags: ios, animation, uiview

I'm new to developing iOS apps, 
I've successfully implemented a Swipe Gesture Recognizer, 
What I was wondering is if there is an easy to use recognizer like the swipe gesture. That would let you implement the homescreen page turning effect but just on a small view in the view controller?

If your unclear on what effect I mean, when you look at the iPhone's homescreen you can drag your finger and it responds instantly (unlike swipe) and also has some spring feeling to it, is this some effect I can use, or do I manually have to program this into the code if so is there a tutorial that explains this?

Thanks,
I hope my question makes sense.

Comment: [UIScrollView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollview_class/Reference/UIScrollView.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `UIPanGestureRecognizer`: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html

> UIPanGestureRecognizer is a concrete subclass of UIGestureRecognizer
>   that looks for panning (dragging) gestures. The user must be pressing
>   one or more fingers on a view while they pan it. Clients implementing
>   the action method for this gesture recognizer can ask it for the
>   current translation and velocity of the gesture.
>
> A panning gesture is continuous. It begins
>   (UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) when the minimum number of fingers
>   allowed (minimumNumberOfTouches) has moved enough to be considered a
>   pan. It changes (UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) when a finger moves
>   while at least the minimum number of fingers are pressed down. It ends
>   (UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) when all fingers are lifted.
>
> Clients of this class can, in their action methods, query the
>   UIPanGestureRecognizer object for the current translation of the
>   gesture (translationInView:) and the velocity of the translation
>   (velocityInView:). They can specify the view whose coordinate system
>   should be used for the translation and velocity values. Clients may
>   also reset the translation to a desired value.

Edit: The spring feeling part you would need to implement yourself. Since iOS 7 there is `UIDynamics` which contains different animators, for what you describe you may need `UIGravityBehavior` and maybe `UICollisionBehaviour`. Look at the WWDC 2013 videos for this topic, I think you will find some examples there.